# Python "trouble shooting machine " needs fixing

Tags: python

The following code is designed to be an automated troubleshooter in Python.

```
# Welcoming the user to the program
print("Hello this is a automated mobile phone troubleshooter ") 
print("The code will ask you a few questions try to answer them to the best of your ability") # Explaining what the code will do

# A list storing all the questions the code will ask the user
questions = ["Is there a problem with your hardware or is do you need technical assistance. Please type technical assistance or hardware",
             "Have you dropped your phone recently? Please type Yes or No",
             "Is your phone able to charge? please type Yes or No",
             "Is your phone a iphone? Please type yes or no",
             "Does your phone keep freezing? Please type yes or no",
             "Can your phone connect to wifi? please type either yes or no",
             "Have you gotten your phone wet? ",
             "Is the phone's screen cracked or broken? ",
             "Is there a problem with the camera? ",
             "Is the problem with phone fixed? "] 
# A list containing all the solutions that will be given to the user
solutions = ["This troubleshooter is only for hardware problems please call 01474 709853 for technical assistance",
             "Please try turning it off and on again",
             "Try changing the cable you charge the phone with",
             "Please hold the lock button and home button for 5 seconds this causes a force restart",
             "Try deleting some data to make your phone run faster E.G. Delete applications",
             "Try restarting your router",
             "Put your phone in a bowl of rice overnight",
             "Take the phone to the manufacturer's store",
             "Uninstall any third party apps or applications that you have downloaded since the camera has not been working",
             "Please take the phone to your local phone manufacturers store and ask them for help"]
answers = ["technical assistance","yes","no","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no"]
validation = ["hardware","no","yes","no","no","yes","no","no","no","yes"]
answer = "a"
# Creating a loop and making the variable loop go from 0 to 9
for loop in range(0,10):
    while answer != answers[loop] and answer != validation[loop]:
        answer = input(questions[loop])
        # Turning the user's answer and turning it to lowercase making sure the IF statement gets the right answer
        answer = answer.lower()    
        if answer == answers[loop]:
            # prints the solution the problem
            print(solutions[loop])
            else goto 

print("Thank you for using the automated troubleshooting program goodbye")
```

I can't get this code to run properly as it can take a max input of two questions before it ends, is there any way someone can help?

Comment: Could you try formatting the code in a code box? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Please format your code properly. If the system doesn't let you ask with a huge code block and little text, there's a reason for it (cc. @MartinGottweis). Your question is lacking information. Please read [ask].

Comment: Last time I saw *goto* was like 25 years ago while playing with c64 basic  :)

Comment: @grubjesic nice catch, I wonder what version of python OP is using if that runs for two questions:)

Answer (score -1):

Whats about doing it with "if statements" and raw_input ?

```
x = raw_input("Is there a problem with your hardware or is do you need technical assistance. Please type technical assistance or hardware")

if x == ("technical assistant"):
    print("This troubleshooter is only for hardware problems please call 01474 709853 for technical assistance")

if x == ("hardware"):
    x1=raw_input("Have you dropped your phone recently? Please type Yes or No")

if x1 == ("No"):
    x2=raw_input("Is your phone able to charge? Please type Yes or No")
```

and so on...

Comment: Your answer is unclear, and it can lead to an undefined `x1` easily.